# alterar keyframe CSS via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3

Estou tentando alterar um `keyframe CSS`, na verdade fazer um update, mas não estou conseguindo `concatenar` variáveis `CSS` à `javaScript`.

A `ideia`, na verdade, nem é alterar. Mas sim, `inserir no final do keyframe` as linhas criadas

Como corrigir isso?

```
       tMin = 0;
       tMax = 20;
       tempoImagens = 20;

       $("@keyframe animacao").css({        

          tMin + "% : margin-left:-" + tempoImagens + "%",
          tMax + "% : margin-left:-" + tempoImagens + "%"   

       });
```

Está dando erro na concatenação.

```
   tMin + "% :
```

Comment: Vc já testou isso? Pq o jQuery retorna erro ao colocar uma arroba (@) no selector: $("@keyframe animacao")

Comment: Sim, de fato deu erro. Mas substitui para $("<style>@keyframe tocaSlide").css(, e o erro passou, porém o keyframe não está sendo populado.

Comment: Em vez de fazer assim .css({ vária linhas }), tenta do modo simples .css('estilo','valor')

Comment: Não dá pois não sei os valores que serão utilizados nem quantas imagens serão colocadas. Só preciso arranjar uma forma de fazer esse keyframe funcionar. Isto é, popular ele,

Comment: Bom, mas nesse formato de múltiplas linhas do .css() vc não irá conseguir fazer concatenação do lado esquerdo do `:`...

Comment: Na verdade eu já consegui, sem erro no browser. Mas o keyframe não está sendo populado

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece porque você está criando uma variável e setando seu valor inicial como inteiro. Daí quando você tenta concatenar, o interpretador "acha" que você está tentando somar, daí ele dá erro, tipo: "COMO SOMAR 20 + 'texto'".

Ao invés de colocar isso:

```
tMin = 0;
tMax = 20;
tempoImagens = 20;
```

Coloque isso:

```
tMin = "0";
tMax = "20";
tempoImagens = "20";
```

Ou você também pode converter o valor de inteiro para texto antes de tentar a concatenação!

Comment: Acredito que isso não aconteça porque ao haver uma string em meio a declaração, o interpretador assume como concatenação. Ex: `""+ 5 + 10 == "510";`